# Adjust results after Import data from local html file

Tags: excel, vba, html-table

With the help of the awesome member @QHarr I had the following code that enables me to scrape data from html local file and it is very fine

```
Sub Test()
Dim html As HTMLDocument, tables As Object, ws As Worksheet, fStream As ADODB.Stream
Dim headers(), mappings(), arr(13), newarr(13), cnt As Long, i As Long, j As Long, n As Long
Dim xFd As FileDialog, sFile As Variant, sSchool As String, sFolder As String, x As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Results")
Set html = New HTMLDocument
Set fStream = New ADODB.Stream
Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
xFd.Title = "Please Select The Original Folder:"
If xFd.Show = -1 Then sFolder = xFd.SelectedItems(1) & "\" Else Exit Sub
sSchool = Split(sFolder, "\")(UBound(Split(sFolder, "\")) - 1)
sFile = Dir(sFolder)

cnt = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row: x = cnt
headers = Array("م", "كود الطالب", "الرقم القومي", "اسم الطالب", "الجنسية", "الديانة", "تاريخ الميلاد", "يوم", "شهر", "سنة", "محافظة الميلاد", "حالة القيد", "النوع", "ملاحظات")
mappings = Array(3, 8, 9, 12, 11, 10, 2, 7, 1, 6, 5, 4, 13)
If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(1, 1).Value) Then ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    While sFile <> ""
        With fStream
            .Charset = "UTF-8"
            .Open
            .LoadFromFile sFolder & sFile
            html.body.innerHTML = .ReadText
            .Close
        End With

        Set tables = html.querySelectorAll("table[width='100%'] table:first-child")

        For i = 89 To tables.Length - 17 Step 26
            Erase arr
            arr(0) = vbNullString

            For j = 0 To 12
                arr(mappings(j)) = Application.Trim(tables.Item(i + (2 * (j))).innerText)
                If j = 4 And arr(3) = "غير مصرى‏" Then arr(mappings(j)) = 0
            Next j

            For j = UBound(arr) To LBound(arr) Step -1
                newarr(n) = arr(j)
                If n = 6 Then
                    If IsDate(newarr) Then newarr(n) = CDate(Day(newarr(n)) & "/" & Month(newarr(n)) & "/" & Year(newarr(n)))
                End If
                n = n + 1
            Next j

            ws.Cells(cnt + 1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(arr) + 1) = newarr
            cnt = cnt + 1: n = 0
        Next i

        sFile = Dir
    Wend

    ws.Cells(x + 1, 14).Resize(cnt - x).Value = sSchool
    ws.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The only problem with the results when there is no nationality id (the third column in the html table) which is الرقــم القومــي
when it is empty I didn't get correct results as for the name and also the following names
If you run the code, notice the rows from 11 to 17 ...
Attachment is the FolderToTest that has the file on this [LINK](http://www.mediafire.com/file/ys7itn33h1cg88y/FolderToTest.rar)

I have tried to work around and somewhat the results are adjusted (but still not correct as the name with the empty nationality id is missing and the following name has some of his data)
Here's my last try

```
Sub Test()
Dim html As HTMLDocument, tables As Object, ws As Worksheet, fStream As ADODB.Stream
Dim headers(), mappings(), arr(13), newarr(13), cnt As Long, i As Long, j As Long, n As Long
Dim xFd As FileDialog, sFile As Variant, sSchool As String, sFolder As String, x As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Results")
Set html = New HTMLDocument
Set fStream = New ADODB.Stream
Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
xFd.Title = "Please Select The Original Folder:"
If xFd.Show = -1 Then sFolder = xFd.SelectedItems(1) & "\" Else Exit Sub
sSchool = Split(sFolder, "\")(UBound(Split(sFolder, "\")) - 1)
sFile = Dir(sFolder)

cnt = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row: x = cnt
headers = Array("م", "كود الطالب", "الرقم القومي", "اسم الطالب", "الجنسية", "الديانة", "تاريخ الميلاد", "يوم", "شهر", "سنة", "محافظة الميلاد", "حالة القيد", "النوع", "ملاحظات")
mappings = Array(3, 8, 9, 12, 11, 10, 2, 7, 1, 6, 5, 4, 13)
If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(1, 1).Value) Then ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
While sFile <> ""
    With fStream
        .Charset = "UTF-8"
        .Open
        .LoadFromFile sFolder & sFile
        html.body.innerHTML = .ReadText
        .Close
    End With

    Set tables = html.querySelectorAll("table[width='100%'] table:first-child")

    For i = 89 To tables.Length - 17 Step 26
        Erase arr
        arr(0) = vbNullString

        For j = 0 To 12
            arr(mappings(j)) = Application.Trim(tables.Item(i + (2 * (j))).innerText)
            'If j = 4 And arr(3) = "غير مصرى‏" Then arr(mappings(j)) = 0
            If j = 3 And Not IsNumeric(Application.Trim(tables.Item(i + (2 * (j)) + 2).innerText)) Then
                i = i + 24
            End If
        Next j

        For j = UBound(arr) To LBound(arr) Step -1
            newarr(n) = arr(j)
            If n = 6 Then
                newarr(n) = CDate(Day(newarr(n)) & "/" & Month(newarr(n)) & "/" & Year(newarr(n)))
            End If
            n = n + 1
        Next j

        ws.Cells(cnt + 1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(arr) + 1) = newarr
        cnt = cnt + 1: n = 0
    Next i

    sFile = Dir
Wend

ws.Cells(x + 1, 14).Resize(cnt - x).Value = sSchool
ws.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You must be running this on a different file? The file I wrote an answer for had no gaps. Have you inspected the table tags of this file?

Comment: Yes I have inspected the tags but there is no tags for this empty cell and this disorder the results. Can we rely on the id 'Section3' .. I noticed there are 16 with the same number of names?

Comment: And I suspect there is no simple way to compensate for this as you won’t know where missing data occurs in advance.

Comment: I am sure that this column only will have the empty if found as it is related to non-egyptians .. so can it be edited so as to suit that column?

Comment: This column will be empty if the governorate column has the string "غير مصرى"

Comment: Can we rely on the id 'Section3' and extract what follows that section? I have no idea how to deal with that but it is just an idea

Comment: I can see a way but it is fiddly.

Comment: Can you give me an idea to start working on it ..? I will do my best to try solving that point as this will save me hours of manual work

Comment: I’ll write an answer but it will be ugly.

Comment: Thanks a lot and I am sure it will be awesome

Comment: I’m just about to post it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refine this the following. I use `Select Case` to test for missing value in `الرقــم القومــي‎` based on value of `محافظة الميلاد‎` . If `محافظة الميلاد‎` is `غير مصرى‏` then I assume there will be an empty later value and adjust the `c` counter I use to populate the array accordingly. I will update to remove some of the unneccessary hard coding.

Note that the mapping is also different here from your previous file.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ParseInfo()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, tables As Object, ws As Worksheet, i As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Results")
    Dim fStream  As ADODB.Stream
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    Set fStream = New ADODB.Stream
    With fStream
        .Charset = "UTF-8"
        .Open
        .LoadFromFile "C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.html"
        html.body.innerHTML = .ReadText
        .Close
    End With
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, currentItem As Variant, missingValueFlag As Boolean
    Set tables = html.querySelectorAll("table")
    Dim mappings(), arr()
    ReDim arr(12)
    mappings = Array(2, 7, 8, 11, 10, 9, 1, 6, 0, 5, 4, 3, 12)
    r = 1: c = 1
    For i = 91 To 504 Step 2
        currentItem = tables.item(i).innerText
        Select Case c
        Case 1
            If currentItem = "غير مصرى‏" Then  
                missingValueFlag = True
            End If
        Case 5
            If missingValueFlag Then c = c + 1
        End Select
        arr(mappings(c - 1)) = currentItem
        If c = 13 Then
            ws.Cells(r, 1).Resize(1, UBound(arr) + 1) = arr
            c = 1: r = r + 1
            missingValueFlag = False
            ReDim arr(12)
        Else
            c = c + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for awesome solution. I will try to adopt to my needs

Comment: I am trying to reorder the results by this line `out = Application.Index(arr, Evaluate("ROW(1:" & UBound(arr) & ")"), [{13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1}])` but I noticed this produced 2 dimensional array. How can I edit this line to make the out array 1 dimensional as arr variable?

Comment: Maybe use application.transpose on it

Comment: I am not clear on what you are trying to do. What is the expected result?

Comment: The expected result is to reverse the order of columns .. as the results should be from right to left

Comment: That's wonderful. Thank you very much. You are really a legend. I have spent about 10 hours trying to solve that problem. You saved me

Comment: Are you starting to see the logic?

Comment: How can I get this text 'نظامي' from css selector or xpath? I inspected class name but found many for it ..

Comment: if it is an innerText (text content) value then you need selenium and xpath. Is it actually a class name?

Comment: OK for selenium but I don't need to rely on the text itself as it will be different

Comment: Is it a text value that can always be matched by position? Sounds like you might need to open a new question with the html and make it really clear what condition you want to meet across files.

Comment: The text will be either of two specific texts or three .. Can it be done with select case or if ..? And will it possible to rely on css selector?

Comment: There is an id with Section3 (16 times) but this text is there in a tag just before the first Section3 id ..  how can I select the first occurrence of Section3 id? I tried `#Section3:nth-of-type(1)` but doesn't return anything